# angular 4 how does a service only update selected components

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a service that gets updates from a signalr hub. These updates contains data for all topics.

The service consumers are some children components, each child component is only interested in one topic.

How do the children components subscribe to only the topic it cares about?

I know I can use a BehaviourObject to update the data, and children components can choose to ignore the update based on the topic. But I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this.

Code in signalr service:

```
    ......
    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    ......
    this.proxy.on('ReceiveData', (data: any) => {              
      this.subject.next(data);    
    });

    getData(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
```

The component that consumes this service:

```
....
this.subscription = this.signalRService.getData().subscribe(data => {
            this.data = data;
        });
....
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
this.subscription = this.signalRService.getData("cars").subscribe(data => {
    // here I only get data about cars
    this.data = data;
});
```

Comment: without knowing much about signalR service, I'd say try using `Observable.filter` to filter the events to what you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

The service getData method could contain an argument to filter the topics that the component needs to subscribe to.

As a side note, you do not need to do

`this.subject.asObservable()`

Given that a Subject is a type of observable

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/subject.md